# jQuery mouseup event not firing on canvas displaying js pdf

Tags: jquery, pdf.js

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638213/plot-coordinates-on-pdf-displayed-in-iframe) question a while back about how to plot co-ordinates on a PDF displayed inline in the browser.

@UselessCode was very helpful with their reply, pointing me towards [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) and supplying [this live demo](http://www.powerlessdynamo.com/stack_exchange/answers/15638213_plot-coordinates-on-pdf-displayed-in-iframe.html) of how to record the co-ordinates of a box dragged onto the page.

I have been experimenting with this on my page and have come across some issues with the mouseup event on the canvas element displaying the PDF.  On **[this example](http://tarakan.chapmanio.co.uk/pdf/pdf.html)** you can see that the mousedown event is fired along with the mousemove event, but not the mouseup event.

```
$(function () {
"use strict";
var startX,
    startY,
    selectedBoxes = [],
    $selectionMarquee = $('#selectionMarquee'),
    $allCords = $('#all-cords'),
    positionBox = function ($box, coordinates) {
        $box.css(
            'top', coordinates.top
        ).css(
            'left', coordinates.left
        ).css(
            'height', coordinates.bottom - coordinates.top
        ).css(
            'width', coordinates.right - coordinates.left
        );
    },

    compareNumbers = function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    },
    getBoxCoordinates = function (startX, startY, endX, endY) {
        var x = [startX, endX].sort(compareNumbers),
            y = [startY, endY].sort(compareNumbers);

        return {
            top: y[0],
            left: x[0],
            right: x[1],
            bottom: y[1]
        };
    },
    trackMouse = function (event) {
        var position = getBoxCoordinates(startX, startY, event.pageX, event.pageY);
        console.log(position);
        positionBox($selectionMarquee, position);
    },
    displayCoordinates = function () {
        var msg = 'Boxes so far:\n';

        selectedBoxes.forEach(function (box) {
            msg += '<li>(' + box.left + ', ' + box.top + ') - (' + (box.left + box.right) + ', ' + (box.top + box.bottom) + ')</li>';
        });
        $allCords.html(msg);
    };


$('#the-canvas').on('mousedown', function (event) {
    startX = event.pageX;
    startY = event.pageY;
    positionBox($selectionMarquee, getBoxCoordinates(startX, startY, startX, startY));
    $selectionMarquee.show();
    $(this).on('mousemove', trackMouse);
}).on('mouseup', function (event) {
    var position,
        $selectedBox;

        $selectionMarquee.hide();

        position = getBoxCoordinates(startX, startY, event.pageX, event.pageY);

        if (position.left !== position.right && position.top !== position.bottom) {
            $selectedBox = $('<div class="selected-box"></div>');
            $selectedBox.hide();
            $('body').append($selectedBox);

            positionBox($selectedBox, position);

            $selectedBox.show();

            selectedBoxes.push(position);
            displayCoordinates();
            $(this).off('mousemove', trackMouse);
        }
});
});
```

I have played around with this and seem to get the mouseup event firing when I add absolute or fixed positioning to the canvas, but then the mousemove event doesn't fire.

I'm sorry to ask a separate question for this but I have tried to revive my previous question to no avail, and I'm really stuck on my project until I can get this part working!