# get X,Y co-ordinates of the selected area from PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf.js, pdf-extraction

I'm trying to extract text from a particular section of a PDF. If I know the X,Y co-ordinates of the area, I'm able to extract the text. But I'm unable to get the co-ordinates of the selected area from PDF. Kindly help me If anyone tried this already.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean. You say that you have X,Y coordinates. You know how to extract text. But which X,Y coordinates do you further need? This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909893/getting-coordinates-of-string-using-itextextractionstrategy-and-locationtextextr/

Comment: Actually I've hard coded the X,Y co-ordinates to extract text. What I need is, When I display the PDF in the browser and selects an area, I need the co-ordinates of the selection. One more doubt I have is, If we get co-ordinates from the browser, Will it be match with Original PDF's co-ordinates.

Comment: The coordinate system in the browser is different from the coordinate system in PDF. There will be differences. This question seems to move more in the direction of pdf.js than in the direction of iText.

Comment: I'm with @BrunoLowagie, this is a client-side problem so iText and PDFbox aren't involved. PDF.js parses a PDF and renders it to the HTML canvas. Knowing that you can just monitor the HTML canvas and ignore the PDF completed. This answer has a sample that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15654197/231316

Comment: Thanks BrunoLowagie and Chris Haas. PDF.js has what I expected...