# object tag in html 5 another web page chrome API

Tags: javascript, html, object, pdf

i use object tag for pdf

```html
<h2>Object</h2>
<div id="div3">
<object data="abc.pdf" height="300" width="500"><p>not supported by object</p></object>
</div>
```

i tried to

```html
var position = document.getElementById('elemId').scrollTop;
```

but it does not work because i write it into my html page.object tag  makes a separate page in which it uses chrome API. My script is in main page not in object auto-generated page.Any Solution ?This is image when i right click on object PDF[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5egv.png)

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you are trying to do ?

Comment: i want to get scroll position of pdf file and store in database so that when user open it browser again (later) open the file where user left ( same scroll position ).i get scroll position  in a simple page using element.scrollTop but in case of iframe it is not working

Comment: ... that's what I was afraid of... You can't. At least, you can't in a cross-browser way, with an `<object>` tag. The `contentDocument` of the object won't be accessible from the top window. What you may try however, is to use [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) library to display your pdf, then you might be able to get all the info you need (e.g check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638213/plot-coordinates-on-pdf-displayed-in-iframe/15654197#15654197))

Comment: but how to use pdf.js .are visual tutorial are available for getting started with pdf.js